# UIButton currentTitle displaying different information that expected

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, xcode

I have the following piece of code

```
- (IBAction)buttonPressed: (id) sender
{
 UIButton *button = (UIButton*) sender;
 NSLog(@"Clicked button is: %d", button.currentTitle);
}
```

The output is:

```
Clicked button is: 26317696
```

Why is not displaying the title of the button which is "A"?

Comment: What does `%d` in a format string print?

Comment: I can't belive I did such a silly mistake. Thanks. Please post an answer and I'll mark it as answered. 

I should have put %@

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(As requested)

`%d` is not the correct format specifier to use.